# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties'

Tags: package-management, python

I have removed and installed python3 on Ubuntu `20.04`, and now I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 12, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties'
```

- I have tried to solve it by installing `software-properties-common`, but that didn't work!
  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-properties-common`
- The version of **Python3** that I have now is: `Python 3.8.10`

Can you please tell me how can I solve it please? thanks in advance.

Comment: Never change default python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install the `python3-software-properties` package as follows:

`sudo apt install --reinstall python3-software-properties`

Comment: No file name for python3-software-properties:amd64